# Get a checkbox checked from button of another page

Tags: wordpress, url, button

in the Page A i have a button, when it is clicked it redirect to Page Z were there is a list of checkboxes and among with them a checkbox with the option Page A! How to make this checkbox get checked from the url/id before in wordpress???

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could make your button append a parameter to the URL it opens.

So instead of opening foo.com/bar you open foo.com/bar?checked=true when your button is clicked.

On the target page then write a javascript that checks if that parameter is set and conditionally set the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with PHP, simply because I like PHP.  From the form on page A you need to submit that checkbox in either a "Get" or "Post" method.  Then on Page Z simply check if the checkbox isset & set the "checked" value for that box. (personally I prefer Post methods so my code uses $_POST, if using Get method replace with $_GET)

On Page Z just modify your checkbox you wish to be already checked from Page A with this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="pageZcheckboxName" value="yourValue" <?php echo (isset($_POST['pageAcheckboxName']) ? 'checked' : ''); ?>>
```